# Is there a way to draw a rounded rectangle without padding in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

Is there a way to make a rounded rectangle with exact height and width? I have looked into `FancyBboxPatch`, but what is seems to do is extending a rectangle with a specified padding to make it rounded. This doesn't work for me because I'm working with a date axis and a mere 0.1 padding creates big rectangles. I'm looking for a workaround without adding anything to the dimensions of the rectangle.

Example:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from matplotlib.patches import Rectangle, FancyBboxPatch
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates

# Create new plot
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

# Create rectangle x coordinates
startTime = datetime(1,1,1,10,0)
endTime = startTime + timedelta(hours = 2)

# convert to matplotlib date representation
start = mdates.date2num(startTime)
end = mdates.date2num(endTime)
width = end - start

# Plot rectangle
rounded_rect = FancyBboxPatch((start, 0), width, 1, boxstyle='Round, pad=0.01', color='yellow', alpha = 0.3)
rect = Rectangle((start, 0), width, 1, color='red')
ax.add_patch(rect)
ax.add_patch(rounded_rect)

# assign date locator / formatter to the x-axis to get proper labels


ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter("%I:%M %p"))

# set the limits
plt.xlim([start-width, end+width])
plt.ylim([-.5, 1.5])

# go
plt.show()
```

[image]

As you can see, the time axis was extended (yellow rectangle). It would have been better to produce rectangles similar to CSS where the rounded corners are made by cutting from edges.

Comment: Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you're asking. Why not set `pad=0`? You can also play with `rounding_size` (see the [doc](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.patches.FancyBboxPatch.html)) to get a render you like:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from matplotlib.patches import Rectangle, FancyBboxPatch
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

# Create rectangle x coordinates
startTime = datetime(1,1,1,10,0)
endTime = startTime + timedelta(hours = 2)

# convert to matplotlib date representation
start = mdates.date2num(startTime)
end = mdates.date2num(endTime)
width = end - start

# Plot rectangle
rounded_rect = FancyBboxPatch((start, 0), width, 1, boxstyle='Round, pad=0, rounding_size=0.05', color='yellow', alpha = 0.5)
rect = Rectangle((start, 0), width, 1, color='red')
ax.add_patch(rect)
ax.add_patch(rounded_rect)

# assign date locator / formatter to the x-axis to get proper labels
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter("%I:%M %p"))

# set the limits
plt.xlim([start-width, end+width])
plt.ylim([-.5, 1.5])

plt.show()
```

Output:

[image]